# How to make a variable using $index values in 2 v-for loops?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to put the days of a month into table using 2 v-for loops.

I want to shorten my code by making a `t_index` variable which equals to `((r_index - 1) * 7 + c_index) - 2` but don't know how to do it reasonably inside the v-for loops.

I tried to use a computed component but it didn't work like intended. So which is the most efficient way to do that?

```html
<tr v-for="r_index in 5">
  <td v-for="c_index in 7" class="p-1">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-left">
        <span v-if="(r_index - 1) * 7 + c_index - 2 === 1">December</span>
        <span v-if="(r_index - 1) * 7 + c_index - 2 > 0 && (r_index - 1) * 7 + c_index - 2 <= 31">{{ (r_index - 1) * 7 + c_index - 2 }}</span>
        <span v-else>&#8203;</span>
      </div>
    </div>                  
  </td>
</tr>
```

[Example for December 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJX5I.png)

Comment: Doing all the logic in the template like that is very difficult to read. It's better to pre-compute the table in a computed property then just render it out.

Comment: I tried using computed but it didn't really work.
```
computed: { t_index(){ return (r_index - 1) * 7 + c_index - 2}},
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy and clean but less known solution:

```html
<tr v-for="r_index in 5">
  <td v-for="c_index in 7" class="p-1">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-left" :set="t_index = ((r_index - 1) * 7 + c_index) - 2">
        <span v-if="t_index === 1">December</span>
        <span v-if="t_index > 0 && t_index <= 31">{{ t_index }}</span>
        <span v-else>&#8203;</span>
      </div>
    </div>                  
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am not the author of this method - I saw it on https://dev.to/pbastowski/comment/7fc9

I will cite it here for completeness:

> For those that may now be thinking, "Hey, I didn't know there was an
> undocumented :set in Vue", there isn't. What I'm doing here is relying
> on the fact that Vue will evaluate the JavaScript of any bound
> attributes and I just chose to invent an attribute called :set.
>
> As a reminder, a bound attribute is one that is prefixed with a : or
> v-bind:. The JavaScript expression inside the double quotes will be
> evaluated in the context of the current component and the item
> variable will still be available outside of the v-for in which it is
> being set. So, it's not a local variable, as such, rather, it's a
> locally assigned component scope (non-reactive) variable.
>
> Do note that this attribute does not have to be declared in your data
> component first. However, if you don't declare it, it will not be
> reactive. In the example above it does not matter to me if it's
> reactive, but it's something to keep in mind if you use this pattern
>
> Here is a fork of Florian's code (thank's Florian) showing the pattern
> at work. [codesandbox.io/s/6nwyw3zzwz](https://codesandbox.io/s/6nwyw3zzwz)

Answer (score 0):

To make the code more readable, use methods.
This `(r_index - 1) * 7 + c_index - 2 === 1` could turn into a method takes `r_index` and `c_index` and returns a boolean.
Same goes for this `(r_index - 1) * 7 + c_index - 2 > 0 && (r_index - 1) * 7 + c_index - 2 <= 31`.
And lastly, create a `t_index` method that takes `r_index` and `c_index` and returns  `(r_index - 1) * 7 + c_index - 2`.